# How much time elapses during the events of the reimagined Battlestar Galactica?

Tags: battlestar-galactica

From the Armistice Station attack to the penultimate scene... How long? Months? Years? And how do we know?

There are some beats like elections and holidays, but it's difficult to say. I'd love to see someone do the math.

Comment: I thin it was said 1-2 years but not 100% there.

Comment: @Thomas That sounds too short. New Caprica was occupied for four months. Also, does Hera age faster than human children?

Comment: @tobiasvl Good point about hera

Comment: I assume you don’t mean the epilogue, right? That’s set something like 100,000 years after the main series.

Comment: Right, that's what I'm referring to when I say penultimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Four years

The timeline actually follows real time, more or less, with one year for each season of the show. We know this from the statements of the characters:

> CAVIL: I know I’m gonna watch you chase your tails across the universe for
> another four years.
>
> <sub>*Battlestar Galactica*, “Daybreak” (S04E20)</sub>

Since the attack on Armistice Station seems to have directly preceded the launching of the fleet, and the "chase your tails across the universe for another four years" must refer to the time since the launching of the fleet, it must have been about four years between the attack on Armistice Station and (non-flashback, non-epilogue) events of this episode.

The final portion of the epilogue, of course, takes place 150,000 years later (give or take):

> NUMBER SIX: She lived in what is now Tanzania, over 150,000 years ago.
>
> GAIUS BALTAR: Along
> with her Cylon mother and human father.
>
> <sub>*Battlestar Galactica*, “Daybreak” (S04E20)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Roughly 5 years, according to [this website,](http://www.thejoekorner.com/battlestargalactica-timeline.shtm) albeit without much citation and an incorrect time index (there are two '3' years). Alternatively, one may also consider that in many TV shows, 1 season equates 1 year. With the 1 year (settlement) and 4 months (occupation) in New Caprica being the only major time jump (that I can recall), I would say 5 is a good estimate.

Comment: What about Cavil’s statement?